# PDO creating a table with a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064

I am having difficulty creating a table with MySQL (PDO) with a foreign key element, without the foreign key the table creates fine, but without I get this message:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I have tried searching for a solution and adapting the code, but seem to keep coming across this. Is there a fix or am I being a wally?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = NULL;
$dbname = "testapplciants";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    //sql to create the activity registered table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE Activity_Register (
    Activity_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    participant_id INT(6) FOREIGN KEY (participant_id) REFERENCES participants,
    entry_number INT(2),
    recorded_result INT(6),
    entry_date TIMESTAMP

    )";

    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Table Activity Recorder created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Can I ask, why are you trying to create your table with PHP code? Isn't it more practical to create it with a Database viewer before accessing it in your project?

Comment: @silkfire While I agree with your sentiment in this case, it can be useful to know such things if dealing with more complex applications that may involve `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Absolutely so, for temporary tables it definitely makes sense, but for reusable tables – out of a developer's point of view – I'd find it much easier to design and construct the table in a  GUI :)

Comment: @silkfire Heh, I have a console that I just type SQL directly into - can't seem to find a GUI that does everything I want. Adminer's pretty good, but only seems to half-heartedly do foreign keys - I have to create the table and then edit the keys to have the parameters I want... Ah well.

Answer (score 2):

`PRIMARY KEY` in a column's definition is shorthand for a *separate* definition that reads `` PRIMARY KEY (`column_name`) ``

`FOREIGN KEY` has no such shorthand.

```
`participant_id` INT(6),
FOREIGN KEY (`participant_id`) REFERENCES `participants` (`id???`)
```

Note that you neglected the column name for the referenced table, and you should probably also have `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` parameters too.

Comment: Thank you Niet the Dark Absol, I tried that and now have uncovered another error. I am a novice developer so have patience :-)   error this time is : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Hi, maybe this could not be the issue but still mentioning, the column which you are going to add as a foreign key has to be indexed.